# "Kernel density estimation" is a convolution of what?

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, convolution

I am trying to get a better understanding of kernel density estimation.

Using the definition from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Definition

$
 \hat{f_h}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h (x - x_i) \quad = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\Big(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\Big)
$

Let's take $K()$ to be a rectangular function which gives $1$ if $x$ is between $-0.5$ and $0.5$ and $0$ otherwise, and $h$ (window size) to be 1.

I understand that the density is a convolution of two functions, but I am not sure I know how to define these two functions. One of them should (probably) be a function of the data which, for every point in R, tells us how many data points we have in that location (mostly $0$). And the other function should probably be some modification of the kernel function, combined with the window size. But I am not sure how to define it.

Any suggestions?

Bellow is an example R code which (I suspect) replicates the settings I defined above (with a mixture of two Gaussians and $n=100$), on which I hope to see a "proof" that the functions to be convoluted are as we suspect.

```
# example code:
set.seed(2346639)
x <- c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50,2))
plot(density(x, kernel='rectangular', width=1, n = 10**4))
rug(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Your rug at the bottom gives some rough intuition. Imagine each value $x_i$ from $i = 1$ to $n$ is a spike with an associated weight $1/n$. Now smear each spike using the shape and width of your kernel, so that the spike is transformed to take on the same shape and width, with a height such that the area below is $1/n$. Add the results and you have a kernel density estimate.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for the comment. This far in the intuition I already got, it is the turning it formally into the form of the convolution which I was curious to see :) (I'm eager to now go through Whuber's answer!)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Corresponding to any batch of data $X = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is its "empirical density function"

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta(x-x_i).$$

Here, $\delta$ is a "generalized function."  Despite that name, it isn't a function at all: it's a new mathematical object that can be used only within integrals.  Its defining property is that for any function $g$ of compact support that is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta(x) g(x) dx = g(0).$$

(Names for $\delta$ include "atomic" or "point" measure and "[Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)."  In the following calculation this concept is extended to include functions $g$ which are continuous from one side only.)

Justifying this characterization of $f_X$ is the observation that

$$\eqalign{
\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(y) dy 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta(y-x_i)dy \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_{-\infty}^{x}  \delta(y-x_i)dy \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_{\mathbb{R}} I(y\le x) \delta(y-x_i)dy \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} I(x_i \le x) \\
&= F_X(x)
}$$

where $F_X$ is the usual empirical CDF and $I$ is the usual characteristic function (equal to $1$ where its argument is true and $0$ otherwise).  (I skip an elementary limiting argument needed to move from functions of compact support to functions defined over $\mathbb{R}$; because $I$ only needs to be defined for values within the range of $X$, which is compact, this is no problem.)

The convolution of $f_X(x)$ with any other function $k$ is given, by definition, as

$$\eqalign{
(f_X * k)(x) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x - y) k(y) dy \\
             &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta(x-y-x_i) k(y) dy \\
             &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \delta(x-y-x_i) k(y) dy \\
             &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} k(x_i-x).
}$$

Letting $k(x) = K_h(-x)$ (which is the same as $K_h(x)$ for symmetric kernels--and most kernels are symmetric) we obtain the claimed result: the Wikipedia formula is a convolution.

Comment: The situation in two dimensions is explained (in more colloquial terms) and illustrated on the GIS site at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/interpretation-of-arcgis-kernel-density-legend-parameters/14376#14376.

Comment: Dear Whuber, I just went through and read your answer with delight! Thank you very much for the explanation and details, your answers (this one, and your others in general) are truly inspiring.

Yours,
Tal

Comment: I think this is called a Dirac comb.

Comment: @Elvis According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb), a Dirac comb corresponds to a *periodic* (and therefore infinite) set of data.  Although the machinery is similar, the concept does not appear to apply to this question.

Comment: Hi, nice answer. I do not understand one thing though. Do we treat the input of the dirac measure as a one-point set? How would we write the above computations if we did not abuse the notation?

Comment: @Jan AFAIK, there is no abuse of notation: $\delta$ is a generalized function in the sense I gave at the outset.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function#Schwartz_distributions for a brief account.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for swift response. Do I understand it correctly, that the empirical density's value $f(x)$ is simply the fraction of points from the sample that attain value $x$? Could you please briefly elaborate on the difference between the dirac function and an indicator function in this context? (I understand that the integral of indicator function would be zero, but in the first sum of your answer they seem the same to me). I can open a new qustion for it if you wish.

Comment: @Jan Your understanding is not quite correct.  There is no empirical "density" in the sense of a finite continuous measure.  The indicator function of the data integrates to zero (whether you use Lebesgue integration or Riemann integration makes no difference).  The generalized function $\delta$ is not a function at all: it's a new mathematical object that can be used only within integrals.  The empirical *distribution* is a mathematical object that, when integrated against any integrable function $g,$ returns the sum (over all data $x_i$) of the values $g(x_i).$

Comment: @whuber Thank you. The sentence *The generalized function δ is not a function at all: it's a new mathematical object that can be used only within integrals.* made it clearer. on point as always. ;)

Comment: @Jan Thank you for your help: I have incorporated that idea within this answer.

Comment: For those struggling with the Dirac-delta function, I wrote a blog post about it. I explain what the Dirac-delta function is and how it can be used for sampling, [here](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.app/post/towards-smc-using-the-dirac-delta-function-in-sampling-and-sequential-monte-carlo/)

Comment: @Euler Please note that $\delta$ is not a function and it is not differentiable at $0.$  It can be conceived of either as a *generalized function* or a *measure.*  In the former sense it does have a derivative--but that derivative is not infinite at zero; it is another generalized function (one that returns the negative derivative of any differentiable function against which it is integrated).

Answer (score 1):

Another convenient way of understanding this connection is from the modeling perspective. Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the PDF of $X+Y$ are the convolution of the marginal PDFs. In kernel density estimation (KDE), we may think about the problem via the following model
$$ X = X' + \varepsilon,$$
where $X'$ has the uniform discrete distribution over the $n$ observed observations $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ with density
$$ f(x') = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta(x'- x_i),$$
as provided above by whuber and $\varepsilon$ is a continuous noise variable independent of $X'$. Then the density of $X$ is their convolution as given by the KDE formula. Depending on the PDF of $\varepsilon$, different kernel functions can be used, e.g., Gaussian kernel.

I believe similar explanations can be made for kernel regression and local linear/polynomial regression, where the focus is more on the mean function. Nevertheless, the mean function is manifested by the density, especially if the Gaussian kernel is used.