# Dirac Delta function Notation

Tags: sampling, density-function, monte-carlo, approximation, dirac-delta

I am trying to understand the delta function notation used to be express a monte carlo approximation of a probability distribution.
The notation used in [this](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Earnaud/doucet_johansen_tutorialPF.pdf) (p10) is

$\pi(x_{1:n}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}\delta_{X^i_{1:n}}(x_{1:n})$

where $X^i_{1:n} \sim \pi(x_{1:n})$ for i=1,..,N

I'm wondering whether this is equivalent to the following

$\pi(x_{1:n}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}\delta(x_{1:n}-{X^i_{1:n}})$

for a specific value of $x_{1:n}$, say $x_{1:n} = y$.
I understand the latter to mean that the probability of a particular $x_{1:n}$ is given by the number of samples that take this value, (hence $\delta(y - X^i_{1:n}) = \delta(0) = 1 )$ divided by the total number of samples, N.

Is this correct?

I realise my questions is similar to the question asked here: [Delta Function in Monte Carlo Sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83091/delta-function-in-monte-carlo-sampling) and have read it and looked at linked answers.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73623.

Comment: This Monte Carlo approximation consists in replacing the unknown distribution $\pi$ with a finite support distribution, which support is the simulated sample $X_{1:n}$. This is also the basis of bootstrap.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about it. I explain what the Dirac-delta function is and how it can be used for sampling, [here](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.app/post/towards-smc-using-the-dirac-delta-function-in-sampling-and-sequential-monte-carlo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's correct. You can see from the wikipedia definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Generalizations) how the generalization with subscript is defined, and your transformation, in the case at hand, renders it back into original delta notation.