# If $Y$ density function of $\frac{3y^2}{\theta^3}\mathbb{1}(y \leq \theta)$, for parameter theta, how do I handle the indicator under integration?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, extreme-value

Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2$ are independent and from a distribution where:

$$
f_\theta(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{3y^2}{\theta^3} &\text{for $0 < y \leq \theta$}, &\theta>0\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Suppose that I want to find the pdf of the maximum of them, ie, I want to find $T = max(Y_1, Y_2)$.

To do this, I have:

\begin{align}
F_T(t) &= P(T \leq t)\\
&= P(max(Y_1, Y_2) \leq t) \\
&= P(Y_1 \leq t, Y_2 \leq t) \\
&= P(Y_1 \leq t) P(Y_2 \leq t)\\
&= \frac{t^6}{\theta^6} \mathbb{1}(t \leq \theta)
\end{align}

I obtained $P(Y \leq t)$ as: $P(Y \leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}f_\theta(y)dy = \frac{t^3}{\theta^3}$

$$
f_T(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{t^6}{\theta^6}\mathbb{1}(t \leq \theta) = \frac{6t^5}{\theta^6} \mathbb{1}(t \leq \theta)
$$

My question here is:

1) When taking the derivative of $\frac{t^6}{\theta^6}\mathbb{1}(t \leq \theta)$, how do I take into account the indicator random variable?

2) For $P(Y \leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}f_\theta(y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{t}\frac{3y^2}{\theta^3}\mathbb{1}(y \leq \theta)dy =  \frac{t^3}{\theta^3}\mathbb{1}(t \leq \theta)$, how do I handle the indicator $\mathbb{1}(y \leq \theta)$ within the integral?

Comment: You should consider the cases $t \leq \theta$ and $t > \theta$ separately.

Comment: @Mur1lo I see, so you are saying that by consider both cases, it becomes a sum and the $t > \theta$ part drops because it's $0$?

Comment: That's it. This means that for $t\geq\theta$ $P(Y\leq t)$ is a constant (= 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the intuition behind an Indicator Function?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239055/what-is-the-intuition-behind-an-indicator-function)