# Can any probability be expressed as an expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value

In section 6.1 of the notes *[Stat 3701 Lecture Notes: Bayesian Inference via Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)](https://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/3701/notes/mcmc-bayes.html)* by Charles J. Geyer, the author states

> Suppose we have a probability or expectation we want to estimate. Probability is a special case of expectation: if $g$ is a zero-or-one valued function, then
> $$
> E\{ g(X) \} = \Pr\{ g(X) = 1 \}
> $$
> and any probability can be written this way. So we just consider expectations.

I would assume that $g$ in this context is the function
$$
g(X) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \ \text{if} \ \ X \in A \\
0 & \ \text{if} \ \ X \notin A
\end{cases}
$$
such that
$$
\Pr\{ g(X) = 1 \} = \Pr\{ X \in A \}
$$
where $A$ is some subset of the range (image) of $X$. Is this true for any random variable $X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can use [indicator function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239055/what-is-the-intuition-behind-an-indicator-function/239058#239058) to define a random variable, say $Y = I_{X\in A}(x)$ and then $Y$ would follow [Bernoulli distributon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with the "probability of success" $p = \Pr(Y=1) = \Pr(X \in A)$. For Bernoulli distribution, expected value is equal to the probability of success $E[Y] = 1 \times p + 0 \times (1-p) = p$.

Comment: Peter Whittle (1927-2021) made this a main theme of his engaging text which passed through two titles, three publishers and four editions between 1970 and 2000.  _Probability via Expectation_ was the later title. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0509-8

Comment: @NickCox it turns out that another book adopts this approach as well: [*A User's Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511811555) by David Pollard (2001). Not only that, but Pollard even cites excerpts from Whittle's book to motivate this approach. Pollard calls this notation ["de Finneti's notation"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiP5NzSxtOCAxX8j2oFHTG4CAkQFnoECA0QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.duke.edu%2F~rnau%2Fdefinettiwasright.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2f4UPYxIuZUgElP3EOMZBG&opi=89978449).

Answer (score 2):

The expectation is a Lebesgue integral with respect to some probability measure $\mu$ in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$,
$$\int f d\mu$$
where $f$ is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function, which in probability are our random variables $X$.

By construction, the Lebesgue integral of an indicator function is the measure of the set associated with that indicator,
$$ \int I_A d\mu = \mu(A), $$
thus under $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$,
$$\mathbb{E}[I_A]=P(X\in A) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$$.