# Sum of Independent Laplacian Variables

Tags: joint-distribution, characteristic-function, laplace-distribution

I have $N$ Independent Random variables Laplacian distributions with $\mu=0$ and positive $b=\sigma^2/2$. I also have dominant random variable $(X_s)$ with  Laplacian distribution with $\mu=0$ and $b=\sigma^2_s/2.$ $(\sigma^2_s \gg \sigma^2).$
I want to find the joint distribution for $$X= \sum_1^N X_i  +X_s$$

My work:
I took the product of the  CF of the random variables on the right to get

$$ \varphi_X(t)= \frac{2}{2+\sigma^2_s t^2} \left( \frac{2}{2+\sigma^2t^2} \right)^N$$

The denominator of this expression can be simplified to

\begin{align}
& (2+\sigma^2_s t^2) (2+\sigma^2t^2)^N \\[6pt]
= {} & (2+\sigma^2_s t^2)(\sigma^2_s)^N(2/\sigma^2_s + \sigma^2/\sigma^2_s t^2)^N \\[6pt]
\approx {} & (2+\sigma_s^2 t^2)2^N
\end{align}

Thus the CF will be that of the $X_s$.

I would like to get some approximate form of the distribution of $X$ based on $N.$ In this approach, I am not able to. Can someone please help?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66763/tight-bounds-on-probability-of-sum-of-laplace-random-variables

Comment: Since they are independent, [you can convolve their distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions#Sum_of_variables). [Convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) might be handy.

Comment: One approach is to express each $X_i$ as a mixture of $Y_i$ and $-Z_i$ where $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are independent Gamma$(1,\sigma)$ variable and use the result at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479 (which also includes a link to a paper on approximating such sums when $N$ is large). // I don't follow your "thus:" for large $N$ that's a very poor approximation.  You need to consider higher powers of $t,$ at least when $N\sigma^2/\sigma_s^2\gg 0.$ // What is "$\sigma_n^2$"?  A typo?

Comment: @Galen Then I would have to convolve these N+1 Laplacian distributions right? That will be a complex distribution I think.

Comment: @wolf_pack_32 That's right; it involves multiple convolutions which gets complicated. I would first explore using a computer algebra system on some chosen values for $N$, and then consider whether those results help me guess what the expansion would look like for the $N+1$ case.

Comment: For large $N$, combine [this approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/615967/214015) with [this approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467366/214015).

Comment: I wonder if someone has worked out an error bound between the distribution and large $N$ approximation. 

Comment: @whuber
That's helpful. Yes, I agree my approximation is bad. So, do I have to factor the ranges of t as well in the C.F?

Comment: The range of $t$ plays no role.  Because this cf is analytic at the origin, its germ there -- essentially, the entire suite of its derivatives at zero -- determines the distribution.  The values of the cf for nonzero $t$ are otherwise irrelevant.  What matters are the magnitudes of the coefficients of those derivatives: the powers of $t,$ multiplied by suitable factorials.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you ought to say "$N$ independent random variables with a Laplacian distribution with $\mu=0$ and $b=\sigma^2/2$" rather than "$N$ Laplacian distributions with..." etc.

Comment: To point you in the correct direction, I wish to remark that a correct analysis of the cf can be obtained *via* the Binomial Theorem as $$\phi_X(t)=(1+\sigma_s^2t^2/2)^{-1}(1+\sigma^2t^2/2)^{-N}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-1}{j}(-\sigma_s^2t^2/2)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-N}{k}(-\sigma^2t^2/2)^k.$$ Expanding in powers of $t$ gives a series $$1+(\sigma_s^2+N\sigma^2)\left(\frac{-t^2}{2!}\right)+3\left(\sigma_s^4+\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\sigma^4+N\sigma_s^2\sigma^2\right)\left(\frac{t^4}{4!}\right)+\cdots.$$ $N$ shows up explicitly, as we would hope.