# What is the distribution of a RV with the constant random variable?

Tags: random-variable, convolution

For random variables (rv) $X$ and $Y$ on a space $\Omega$:

Assume the rv $X\sim f_0$ distributed and $Y(t)=c$ is a constant rv, i.e. $Y\sim \delta(t-c)$ using the $\delta$-distribution as a short notation. Using the convolution I get $X+c \sim f_0(y-c)$. (I think $X$ and $Y$ are independent as $\{t|Y(t) \in B\} = \Omega$ ($B$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$).)

Question: is this correct? If yes, ist there a good intuitive explanation for the shift?

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73623.

Comment: @whuber if I understand correctly, my results are correct and the question can be viewed as a special case of your linked question?

Comment: Indeed, yes.  You can take $f_0$ to be the kernel and $c=x_1$ to be a single data point.  Another approach begins by observing [the convolution is the distribution of the sum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331973) $Y+X.$